# swagger parameter - title overrides XML object for root object in schema

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

```
  parameters:
    - name: message
      in: body
      schema:
        type: object
        title: Ping_Request
        xml:
          name: message
```

in swagger ui the example for this would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Ping_Request>
```

For nested objects it works ok (uses tag name from XML object, not from title for this object).
And for result schema root object it's also ok.

The problem for root object in body parameter only.

Comment: Workaround that I found - use $ref, in this case everything is ok, but I want to have specification inside message description, not in definitions section of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

It was likely a bug in the Swagger UI version that you used. Version 3.0.5 renders the XML example with the correct root tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
</message>
```